# How can I get colorful input tags?

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I am working on my practice project and want to get such a jaw droping coloured tags.
Can someone please explain me how can I get them ,which libaray to use !

[image]

Comment: A few `padding`, `border-radius` and `background-color`, super easy CSS, no framework needed.

Comment: I don’t wanna to enter background colour separately !

Comment: Each tag should get background colour by iteration.

Comment: You can have the background colours predefined in the css and then add the class names dynamically to your tags within your logic of building them.

Comment: oh thnks @ConsoleLog it make some scence . :)

Comment: No worries. glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jordi explained, it's pretty easy to do with some very basic css.

```
.label{padding: 5px 10px; color: #fff;}
.red{background-color: #da4453}
.blue{background-color: #3bafda;}

<span class="label red">red label</span>
<span class="label blue">blue label</span>
```

Bootstrap, Foundation and few other frameworks are there if you want to use predefined stuff, but would be an overkill if you only want to accomplish this.

Bootflat has a good colour scheme - http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html

Comment: Is Bootflat able to give them background colour by iteration!

Comment: Bootflat is only a framework, it won't give your colours by iteration. You can implement the iteration in the logic, whether it's angular or backend language but the predefined colour classes can stay in the css, if that makes sense?